# Is there a way to prompt the user for the input method on android?

Tags: android, keyboard

I want to make a custom keyboard for my word game app. But it's not
very user friendly for the user to go to Language Settings and enable
it there and then hold on some text input and select my custom input
method. Is there a built-in call that i could use to prompt the user
to select a input method on the app start? Something like when you're
prompted to turn on bluetooth and bt disovery. If this is not possible
would it be a memory hog to create my own View with buttons on it that
would simulate the keyboard and send chars to the EditText or TextView
for displaying what is currently typed in.

Comment: I've found the perfect solution [here](http://www.infiniterecursion.us/2011/02/android-activity-custom-keyboard.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can just start an Activity using the following Intent :

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS));
```

You can get more information on [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html)

Comment: How can i check what input method is current, so that i can deny game starting if the right input method hasn't been selected?